# Display html template in kendo dialog in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I have a simple method which gets html from server and opens the dialog on button click as below:

The template being passed in the below code is a sample html.
For eg. 
Test

The kendo-dialog opens but it displays the contents as is with the tags instead of rendering  it.

```
      const dialog: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
        title: "Please confirm",
        content:  template,
        actions: [{ text: "No" }, { text: "Yes", themeColor: "primary" }],
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
        minWidth: 250
      });
```

In the constructor I have -> private dialogService: DialogService

I am importing from:
import {
DialogService,
DialogRef,
DialogCloseResult,
} from "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog";

I tried to convert the string in HtmlAttribute but then content won't take that.
Any reference or inputs will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In the template for the dialog content, do this:

```
<ng-template #dialogTemplate>
    <div [innerHTML]="dialogContentHTML"></div>
</ng-template>
```

You'll probably need to sanitize the HTML before you can use it.

Add this import:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

Add this to your constructor parameters (DI):

```
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
```

When you get the result from the server, use it like this:

```
this.dialogContentHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(result);
```

You'll probably also need to call `this.changeDetector.markForCheck();` since the change will happen asynchronously.